# What is the proper way to implement a 'toJson' function in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a custom class, and I need a `toJson` function. Of course, I can just implement a function called `Foo.toJson` or `Foo.toJsonObject` or `Foo.jsonify`.

But what would be the standard way of doing this? I also saw some examples which include a `serializer`. Do I need to go that far?

Basically I want to be able to make this work:

```
const foo = new Foo();
fse.writeJson('file.json', foo);
```

But for a database connection I also need to be able to manually create a json representation:

```
const foo = new Foo();
db.writeObject(foo.toJson());
```

Comment: You... you don't? It's already baked into JavaScript as the [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) object, and by extension, Typescript. JSON captures your data, what you actually need is a constructor, or static factory, that will yield your properly-classed-object based on the pure data you get from parsing a JSON serialization. _Creating_ JSON is a matter of `const stringData = JSON.stringify(yourobj)`, or if you want it to stay human-readable, `const stringData = JSON.stringify(yourobj, false, 2)` to get some nice indentation in there.

Comment: `let foo: Foo = JSON.parse('{"id": 4, "title": "string"}');` ...also see https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#type-assertion-vs-casting

Comment: For the benefit of people who haven't come across it before, a [`toJSON` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description) on an object tells `JSON.stringify()` how to convert that object to JSON (for example, you can special case non-iterable properties or recursive references)

Comment: @Quentin That's exactly what I was looking for! I could accept this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't just modify the original class:

1. Declare a new type which adds the toJSON method to the original type
2. Cast the object to the new type
3. Assign the toJSON method to it

For example:

```js
class Foo {
    public date: Date;

    constructor(date: Date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    log() {
        console.log(this.date.toISOString());
    }
}

type ExtendedFoo = Foo & {
    toJSON: () => string;
}

const x = new Foo(new Date);

(x as ExtendedFoo).toJSON = function () {
     return `"\\/Date(${+this.date})\\/"`
}

x.log();
console.log(x);
```